# Unity - Renderer "raycasts" from top down?

Tags: unity, 2d, raycasting

I'm trying to have objects in a game be selectable only from a **top down orthographic camera view**. I think having physics colliders might be overkill for that - especially because this only needs to be in 2D and not 3D. Is there another method that might be better, such as something like a renderer "raycasts", but perhaps even more performant as it is just from the orthographic 2D top down view

Answer (score 1):

If you build your "top down" view on the XY plane, you can use 2D colliders and `Physics2D.OverlapPoint`.

This is about as efficient as you will get. A 2D collider is using exactly the same math you'd need to write in your C# code to test for a hit anyway. And if you're using Kinematic bodies on a physics layer that doesn't interact with anything, they won't burn any cycles on unneeded collision detection and resolution.

Comment: is there a way to automatically create 2D colliders from the top down for 3D meshes?

Comment: You could write a script to do it reasonably easily. Project all the triangles and make a polygon collider out of their perimeter.

Comment: Or you could use `GetComponent<Renderer>().bounds` which gets you the [bounding box](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Bounds.html) of the object as its used for culling calculations and create a BoxCollider2D out of it.

Answer (score -1):

you can use quadtree algorithm to detect which object under the mouse position

you can use octree algorithm in 3d space

Comment: Why would you do that when Unity already provides that for you?

Comment: some people like inventing the sledgehammer even though it is now commodity that's basically free

Comment: Some times you dont need whole physics features with heavy calculations

Comment: Im using ECS and i had to use this algorithm for nearby object detection